# com.apple.main-threadEXC_BREAKPOINT, Crash registered on Fabric on Fetching User Facebook Profile in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

There is a crash registered on Fabric in my app when I am fetching user's facebook profile information. It is only crashing on release build. I am not able to reproduce the crash even after trying it multiple times. I am fetching the profile in a separate network manager class. I have implemented it using closure and callbacks.

Below is the stack trace and crash report from Fabric.

```
# OS Version: 11.4.1 (15G77)
# Device: iPhone 6s
# RAM Free: 6%
# Disk Free: 14.3%

#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  Roamer                         0x104b364a4 LoginViewController.(fetchUserProfile() -> ()).(closure #1) (LoginViewController.swift:250)
1  Roamer                         0x104b36d84 partial apply for LoginViewController.(fetchUserProfile() -> ()).(closure #1) (LoginViewController.swift)
2  Roamer                         0x104b7ed4c specialized NetworkManager.(fetchFBProfile(((display : Int, status : String, message : String), FBProfileResponse) -> ()) -> ()).(closure #1) (NetworkManager.swift:1234)
3  Roamer                         0x104b7e7a4 partial apply for NetworkManager.(fetchFBProfile(((display : Int, status : String, message : String), FBProfileResponse) -> ()) -> ()).(closure #1) (NetworkManager.swift)
4  Roamer                         0x104b7e7ec HTTPURLResponse?GraphRequestResult<MyProfileRequest> (NetworkManager.swift)
5  FacebookCore                   0x1058dc550 HTTPURLResponse?GraphRequestResult<A> (GraphRequestConnection.swift)
6  FacebookCore                   0x1058daaac (HTTPURLResponse?, GraphRequestResult<A>)() (GraphRequestConnection.swift)
7  FacebookCore                   0x1058dc8d8 static GraphRequestConnection.sdkRequestCompletion<A where ...> (from : (HTTPURLResponse?, GraphRequestResult<A>) -> ()) -> (FBSDKGraphRequestConnection?, Any?, Error?) -> () empty-list Error first-element-marker HTTPURLResponse (GraphRequestConnection.swift:152)
8  FacebookCore                   0x1058dac18 static GraphRequestConnection.sdkRequestCompletion<A where ...> (from : (HTTPURLResponse?, GraphRequestResult<A>) -> ()) -> (FBSDKGraphRequestConnection?, Any?, Error?) -> () empty-list Error first-element-marker HTTPURLResponse (GraphRequestConnection.swift)
9  FacebookCore                   0x1058dc5f8 FBSDKGraphRequestConnection?Any?Error? (GraphRequestConnection.swift)
10 FacebookCore                   0x1058dc4bc (FBSDKGraphRequestConnection?, Any?, Error?)() (GraphRequestConnection.swift)
11 FacebookCore                   0x1058c58bc FBSDKGraphRequestConnection?Any?Error? (AccessToken.swift)
12 FBSDKCoreKit                   0x1056a43fc -[FBSDKGraphRequestMetadata invokeCompletionHandlerForConnection:withResults:error:] (FBSDKGraphRequestMetadata.m:48)
13 FBSDKCoreKit                   0x1056a1d2c __82-[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection processResultBody:error:metadata:canNotifyDelegate:]_block_invoke (FBSDKGraphRequestConnection.m:754)
14 FBSDKCoreKit                   0x1056a1b88 -[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection processResultBody:error:metadata:canNotifyDelegate:] (FBSDKGraphRequestConnection.m:818)
15 FBSDKCoreKit                   0x1056a163c __64-[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection completeWithResults:networkError:]_block_invoke (FBSDKGraphRequestConnection.m:738)
16 CoreFoundation                 0x1825a0a20 -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 216
17 FBSDKCoreKit                   0x1056a13e0 -[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection completeWithResults:networkError:] (FBSDKGraphRequestConnection.m:717)
18 FBSDKCoreKit                   0x1056a087c -[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection completeFBSDKURLSessionWithResponse:data:networkError:] (FBSDKGraphRequestConnection.m:582)
19 FBSDKCoreKit                   0x10569ea54 __36-[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection start]_block_invoke_2 (FBSDKGraphRequestConnection.m:222)
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x181fb8aa0 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
21 libdispatch.dylib              0x181fb8a60 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
22 libdispatch.dylib              0x181fc565c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 1012
23 CoreFoundation                 0x18266f070 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
24 CoreFoundation                 0x18266cbc8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2272
25 CoreFoundation                 0x18258cda8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
26 GraphicsServices               0x184572020 GSEventRunModal + 100
27 UIKit                          0x18c5ac758 UIApplicationMain + 236
28 Roamer                         0x104b1fbf8 main (DetailsCell.swift:28)
29 libdyld.dylib                  0x18201dfc0 start + 4

--
```

Below is the function in LoginViewController from where I am calling the fetchFBProfile function in NetworkManager:

```
func fetchUserProfile()
{
    NetworkManager.sharedInstance.fetchFBProfile() { [unowned self] (responseStatus: ResponseStatus, responseObj: FBProfileResponse) in

        if responseStatus.status == "Success"
        {
            self.fbSignIn(responseObj)
        }
        else{
            if responseStatus.display == 1
            {
                self.showBanner(Strings.failureHeaderMsg, responseStatus.message, true, true)
            }
            else{
                self.showBanner(Strings.failureHeaderMsg, Strings.serverErrorMsg, true, true)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the fetchFBProfile function in NetworkManager:

```
func fetchFBProfile( _ completion: @escaping GenericResponseWithObj<FBProfileResponse>) -> Void {
            let connection = GraphRequestConnection()
            progress.show(style: ProgressStyle())
            connection.add(MyProfileRequest()) { response, result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let response):

                    let fBProfileResponse = FBProfileResponse()
                    fBProfileResponse.birthday = response.birthday
                    fBProfileResponse.email = response.email
                    fBProfileResponse.gender = response.gender
                    fBProfileResponse.id = response.id
                    fBProfileResponse.locale = response.locale
                    fBProfileResponse.name = response.name
                    fBProfileResponse.profilePictureUrl = response.profilePictureUrl

                    completion((0, "Success", "Facebook SignIn Successful"), fBProfileResponse)

                case .failed(let error):
                    print("Custom Graph Request Failed: \(error)")
                    self.progress.dismiss()
                    completion((0, "Failure", "Couldn't fetch user response"), FBProfileResponse())
                }
            }
            connection.start()
        }
```

I can't understand the crash report from fabric and also the app is working flawlessly on my end. Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks

Comment: why did you make self unowned? why not weak? it may be potential cause of the crash

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I've made it unowned because I think It won't be nil during this call. Should I change it to weak? How would that help?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha I tried weak and still it crashed.